# Is it possible to invert this mapping?

Tags: linear-algebra

This may be a silly question, but any help would be appreciated.

Suppose 
$$\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & -1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 1 & -1 \end{array} \right)\cdot x=y$$ and $x$ is a 3x1 vector.

Is it possible to invert the mapping $x\to y$?

Comment: It depends on $y$. For some there are no such $x$'s, for some there's more than one $x$.

Comment: Is there a way to be sure about which $y$s can be inverted?

Comment: No $y$ can be 'inverted', because being inverted means that you can find one, and only one, $x$ that does the job. If you mean to ask for which $y$'s we can find at least one $x$, then those are the ones in the span of the columns of the matrix. You should also clarify the question because the title asks one thing, but your question asks something else.

Comment: Thank you. I Already understood the problem, and it doesn't seem like it will add much to math.se, should I delete this question?

Comment: No, at this moment you shouldn't delete the question because three people already lost the time to given an answer. What you should do is clarify the question so that it becomes something of value to MSE. As it is the answers so far answer the question in the title, but in the question box you're asking something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the determinant of the matrix is zero, it is impossible to invert the mapping.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If $y=\left(\begin{matrix}0\\0\\0 \end{matrix}\right)$, what happens when you solve for $x$?

Answer (score 0):

The matrix has rank $2$, wich can be seen by summing columns one and two and comparing to column three:
$$M_1 + M_2 + M_3 = 0$$
is a nontrivial linear combination wich adds up to $0$.
What does that imply for invertibility of $Mx = y$?